# Regular Expressions, group elements in a list

Tags: regex, swift

I'm parsing an html page - converting it to a full string - and what I get is a list that I would be able to split into sections. Here's what I mean:

```
chemestry    // subject name

21/10        // date of the exam

6+           // value of the first mark

25/12        // date of the second exam

8            // value of the second mark

physics      // subject name [and so on...]

27/11

10
```

the app I'm building will display a tableview representing each subject, if a cell is clicked the user will see the list of marks that he got in that specific subject.

What I need to do is let the "compiler" know that a **string** represents the subject name, two integers split by a "**/**" represents the mark's date and a **single integer** (eventually followed by a + or -) is the mark's value. Also, each time the compiler encounter a new string it'll mean that a new and different subject is being parsed.

How can I achieve this? Thank you very much for your help in advance

Comment: Please post some of the text you want to analyse.

Comment: Consider to use a libxml based parser, it's much more convenient than regex.

Comment: @some-non-descript-user basically a little excerpt of the text is provide in the code area of my question, here's the full text anyway http://pastebin.com/bbDYkpTe

Comment: @vadian actually I would parse only the string result, the real html page is parsed through Kanna (html parsing for Swift) and that's fine, what you see is the combined of multiple paragraphs (<p>) with the same class

Comment: Then it might be easier to parse the html more specific and validate the input right there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
[a-z ]+\s*(?:[^a-z]+?\d{2}/\d{2}[^a-z]+?\d+½?[+-]?)+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/eM3mD4/2

Comment: Thank you, this did the job flawlessly!